# Properties on Application not persisting between Service and Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

The problem is that when accessing TaskTimerApplication.TEST from the activity, it is still "Creation", but in the service it is "Modification" like it should be. I have already made 100% sure that my service is executing its code before the activity is accessing the data. Below is a simple test scenario that presents the problem in a more obvious way.

Application code:

```
public class TaskTimerApplication extends Application {
    // Static properties
    private static final String TAG = "Application";
    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    public static String TEST = "Declaration";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        TEST = "Creation";
        Log.v(TAG, "Created");
    }
}
```

Service code:

```
public class TaskService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "TaskService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        TaskTimerApplication.TEST = "Modification";
        Log.d(TAG, TaskTimerApplication.TEST);
    }
}
```

My full, non-test code can be seen at my [GitHub project](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/tree/master/android). In the full code, the TASKS ArrayList stays empty in the activity, but is properly filled in the service.

Comment: If these are the only two place that you change TaskTimerApplication.TEST, you can't be 100% sure that your service is exeucting its code before the activity (otherwise, the TEST value wouldn't be "Creation"). Put a breakpoint a both spots and in your Activity and see what happens.

Comment: But in my full code, if you take a look, you can see that the activity is sending a message to the service, and the service responds. The activity then, on response, accesses the data. So I am indeed 100% sure that the service's code is executing first. Also, if I log the value of TaskTimerApplication repeatedly when a button is pressed, it's _always_ the same result.

Comment: Did you try to execute the test scenario? I'd expect it to work. It must be something related to your more complicated real world example. What are the fields in your app? Is it "groups" variable?

Comment: The onCreate of TaskService could be called way before the onStartCommand of TaskService. Also, why are you both starting and binding the service and why are you doing on the work in the service's onCreate instead of its onStartCommand?

Comment: @fedepaol When I created this test scenario, I added it to the code of my actual app. The results were the same. And yes, it is both GROUPS and TASKS.

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston I am both starting and binding because the service is intended to run in the background even after the app is closed (hence the starting), and need to be able to tell when the activity and service are connected (hence the binding).

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston Also, I need to communicate between the two.

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston Oh, and I'm doing all the work in onCreate because the service persists when the app is exited; when the app is opened again, I don't want all that code to execute again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in your manifest:

```
<service android:description="@string/service_description" android:name=".TaskService" android:label="@string/service_label" android:process=":TaskService"></service>
```

There is usually no good reason to waste RAM and CPU by putting your service in a separate process. Moreover, if you do put the service in a separate process, then your activity and your service will not be in the same process and therefore will not share a common `Application` object instance.

My recommendation is to drop the `android:process` attribute.

Comment: When I don't have it running in its own process, the app freezes instantly upon startup - an actual freeze, not just crash.

Comment: @Gawdl3y: Then you have a bug in your code. You need to fix your bug. Forking a second process to hide some bug in your code is not a wise move on any platform.

Comment: It's always been in a separate process, that's not something I did to work around an issue. Also, the service is intended to be running in the background, even when the app is closed. Additionally, there's no infinite loop or anything that I can think of, so I don't see a reason for it to be freezing. I'll go ahead and start spamming log messages everywhere to see if I can find the source of the freezing.

Comment: @Gawdl3y: Bear in mind that service lifecycle methods (`onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, `onDestroy()`) are called on the main application thread. This is the same thread that drives your UI. If you try doing something long in those lifecycle methods, it will freeze your UI and cause an ANR after several seconds. Long-running stuff like that should be on a background thread.

Comment: Not relevant with the question, but note also that static data may disappear from your application singleton the first time the os needs your app resources. The next time it will be created again the values will be erased

Comment: @CommonsWare There's nothing long-running. I did manage to narrow it down a bit, though. It appears to be freezing once the activity sends the initial message to the service.

Comment: @CommonsWare The service is going to also be handling SQLite access, which is one of the reasons why I had it in a separate process in the first place.

Comment: @Gawdl3y: There is no reason for using a separate process for SQLite access.

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe not for JUST SQLite access, but it's also going to function as a timer that runs in the background. I'm currently looking into how AOSP does its stopwatches in the 4.2 clock app; I might end up changing a ton of stuff.

Comment: @Gawdl3y: "but it's also going to function as a timer that runs in the background" -- that doesn't even need a service at all, let alone one running constantly, let alone one that uses a second process.

Comment: @CommonsWare How does that not require at least a service? It needs to be running even when the app isn't.

Comment: @Gawdl3y: Time elapses even when there is no code running. If there is no UI, there is no need to watch the clock tick. Simply record the start time to a file/database/preference/whatever. Use that data again when you have a UI to present.

Comment: @CommonsWare But then I can't notify the user once a task has reached its goal, if there's nothing running in the background. In addition, in the future I'll be adding notifications that allow you to view the task time/progress/etc (probably expandable to pause/start, as well).

Comment: @Gawdl3y: "But then I can't notify the user once a task has reached its goal, if there's nothing running in the background" -- use `AlarmManager`, rather than keeping a process around constantly. "In addition, in the future I'll be adding notifications that allow you to view the task time/progress/etc (probably expandable to pause/start, as well)" -- and in the future, you will have more experience with Android development and can weigh the merits of such features with their costs to the user.

Comment: @CommonsWare And that's why I'm providing the option to change the update rate in the background (foreground, too). Chances are I'll end up adding a toggle for the notifications completely, as well.